# Change Control for Servers /hardware and software updates

Tags: windows

Anyone know of any good change control software? Mainly for logging changes to servers by the admin guys.

Comment: Sorry windows only so no puppet :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can start with any simple ticketing system. I like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) myself, but there are many others out there.

The process that I typically go through, for a small team, is as follows.

1. Issue is identified.
2. Ticket is created with basic description.
3. Ticket is updated with findings and plan of action.
4. Remedy work is undertaken.
5. Ticket is updated. Closed if fixed. Or repeat to step 3.
6. Record persistent changes in a shared document.

We use Trac's wiki for shared documentation. A wiki page is created for each machine/service type which details it's build, prerequisites, deliverables and quirks. Documents are easy to format and edit. The whole lot is searchable and easily referable.

We also use Puppet and version control other configs, so use commit-hooks to reference tickets. But you don't necessarily have to go that far just to benefit.

The most important detail is enforcing every engineer to follow the same workflow. If they don't, then you're wasting your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet/) is awesome for this kind of thing

Comment: Could you share your manifests for managing hardware changes using Puppet?

Comment: I'm a bit lost with puppet, I'm just looking for something simple that the whole team can use. I wish I had the time to set it up but I don't :-(

Comment: I don't use puppet myself. He didn't mention hardware changes-'change control' is typically understood to mean software changes